# C# User control with custom ControlDesigner each copy

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I need some help with user controls.
I have a user control which has a custom ControlDesigner:

In the designer I change the SelectionRules if I change a specific property at the user control.

The Problem I have is the following:
When I place multiple copies of this user control and change the property, the designer will change the SelectionRules for all copies.

How do I set this up for each copy?

Here is the code:

```
[Designer(typeof(BorderedTextBox_Designer))]
public partial class BorderedTextBox : UserControl
{
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Description("Controls whether the text of the edit control can span more than one line.")]
    [Category("Behavior")]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    public bool Multiline
    {
        set
        {
            //Set to TRUE:
            if (value)
            {
                BorderedTextBox_Designer.SelectionRule = BorderedTextBox_Designer.SelectionRulesEnum.All;
            }
            //Set to FALSE:
            else
            {
                BorderedTextBox_Designer.SelectionRule = BorderedTextBox_Designer.SelectionRulesEnum.RightLeft;
            }
        }
    }
}

internal class BorderedTextBox_Designer : ControlDesigner
{
    internal static SelectionRulesEnum SelectionRule;

    public override SelectionRules SelectionRules
    {
        get
        {
            switch (SelectionRule)
            {
                case SelectionRulesEnum.All:
                    return SelectionRules.Visible | SelectionRules.Moveable | SelectionRules.AllSizeable;
                case SelectionRulesEnum.UpDown:
                    return SelectionRules.Visible | SelectionRules.Moveable | SelectionRules.TopSizeable | SelectionRules.BottomSizeable;
                case SelectionRulesEnum.RightLeft:
                    return SelectionRules.Visible | SelectionRules.Moveable | SelectionRules.LeftSizeable | SelectionRules.RightSizeable;
                case SelectionRulesEnum.None:
                    return SelectionRules.Visible | SelectionRules.Moveable;
                default:
                    return SelectionRules.Visible | SelectionRules.Moveable;
            }
        }
    }

    internal enum SelectionRulesEnum
    {
        All,
        UpDown,
        RightLeft,
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't set designer properties via static members, rather use events (see [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973820.aspx)), in events you get instance of control which property is changed and can adjust designer property there.

Comment: Thank you!!! This helped!
Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: I would not be able to post good answer (just a hint as comment). But [you can](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Okay, I'll do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. Thanks to [Sinatr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1997232/sinatr) for the hint :)

The answer is to set the property to the instance of the ControlDesigner from the user control.

And not to the static class => in this case the property changes will be global as my problem is.

Here a code sample:

```
//The UserControl you created
[Designer(typeof(UserControlDesigner))]
[DefaultEvent("TextChanged")]
public partial class UserControl : UserControl
{
    //The property where we will store the UserControlDesigner instance when it is created
    internal UserControlDesigner Designer;

    //Initialize the UserControl
    public UserControl()
    {
        //Check for design time
        if (DesignMode)
            //Set the individual value to this UserControlDesigner instance's property
            Designer.DesignerProperty = 1;
    }
}

//The custom ControlDesigner should used to design your UserControl
internal class UserControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    //The UserControl which is designed with this instance
    internal UserControl DesignedControl;

    //The Property you want to change each copy of your UserControl individually
    internal int DesignerProperty;

    //The method which is called when the UserControlDesigner instance is created
    public override void Initialize(IComponent component)
    {
        base.Initialize(component);

        //Cast the IComponent which is designed with this designer instance to your UserControl class
        DesignedControl = component as UserControl;

        //Check for successful cast
        if (DesignedControl != null)
            //Store this UserControlDesigner instance in the property "Designer" which we've created to access the instance in design time
            DesignedControl.Designer = this;
    }
}
```